# Java Regex to replace sequence string with bullet operators and black square

Tags: java, regex, unicode

I have an XML file which describes an odt file content.
I would replace char sequences which give problems with bullet operators and black square using Java.

In particular, given the following XML element:

```
<text:list-level-style-bullet text:level="1" text:style-name="Bullet_20_Symbols" style:num-suffix="." text:bullet-char="â?¢">
            <style:list-level-properties text:space-before="0.25in" text:min-label-width="0.25in" />
</text:list-level-style-bullet>
```

I want to replace with a regex the â?¢ sequence with the [bullet operator](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2219/index.htm).

Similarly, given

```
<text:list-level-style-bullet text:level="2" text:style-name="Bullet_20_Symbols" style:num-suffix="." text:bullet-char="â?£">
            <style:list-level-properties text:space-before="0.5in" text:min-label-width="0.25in" />
</text:list-level-style-bullet>
```

I want to replace with a regex the â?£ sequence with [white bullet](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25e6/index.htm).

At last, similarly to the previous case I want to replace with a regular expression the â?? sequence with [black square](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25a0/index.htm).

So, given the file content in a String (*result* variable), I tried to use the *replaceAll* method with regex as follow:

```
result = result.replaceAll("â[?]¢", "\u2219");
result = result.replaceAll("â[?]£", "\u25E6");
result = result.replaceAll("â([?]){2}", "\u25A0");
```

This code has no effect, the regular expression match correctly the part of the text which I want (I try with [Rubular](http://rubular.com/)), and I specify the specific unicode for the symbol that I want to use to substitute.

Can someone help me?
Thank you.

Comment: `replace` does not accept a regex, but a simple string. Use `replaceAll`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry. I copied the wrong portion of code, now I'm using this `result = result.replaceAll("â[?]¢", "\u2219");
        result = result.replaceAll("â[?]£", "\u25E6");
        result = result.replaceAll("â([?]){2}", "\u25A0");` but nothing to do.

Comment: [It works](https://ideone.com/vI8Sji), check the demo.

Comment: Finally I solved.
The problem was the encoding, after to update the string content of the file, I tried to save it to a temporary file: the replacing with regex works correctly but when I wrote the file the new character were encoded wrong.
So I use the ISO-8859-15 encoding intead UTF-8 and a OutputStreamWriter.